# odoo get several data in text field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have this py script

```
@api.one
@api.depends('customer_id')
def _get_unpaid_list(self):
    invoice_pool = self.env['account.invoice']
    for rec in invoice_pool.search([('state', '=', 'open'), ('partner_id', '=', self.customer_id.id)]):
        amount_total = rec.amount_total or ''
        number = rec.number or ''
        name = ustr(amount_total) + "-" + ustr(number)
        self.unpaid_list = name
unpaid_list = fields.Text(string="Customer Debt List", compute="_get_unpaid_list", )
```

and this xml

```
<field name="unpaid_list" />
```

It works with this output

```
19690000.0-INV/2021/13928
```

BUT it should show several line of data like this

```
19690000.0-INV/2021/13928
25590000.0-INV/2021/13929
23450000.0-INV/2021/13930
```

How to make a list of data like it should?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `unpaid_list` is set to the last `name` in the loop. To fix the issue, you need to set the field value outside the for loop.

***Example:***

```
@api.depends('customer_id')
def _get_unpaid_list(self):
    invoice_pool = self.env['account.invoice']
    for record in self:
        name = ''
        for invoice in invoice_pool.search([('state', '=', 'open'), ('partner_id', '=', record.customer_id.id)]):
            amount_total = invoice.amount_total or ''
            number = invoice.number or ''
            name += ustr(amount_total) + "-" + ustr(number) + "\n"
        record.unpaid_list = name
```

You can use a computed `One2many` field to show the list of unpaid invoices and let users open (the invoice form) and view the invoice details.

***Example:***

```
@api.depends('customer_id')
def _get_unpaid_invoices(self):
    invoice_pool = self.env['account.invoice']
    for record in self:
        record.unpaid_list_ids = invoice_pool.search([('state', '=', 'open'), ('partner_id', '=', record.customer_id.id)])

unpaid_list_ids = fields.One2many("account.invoice", string="Customer Debt List", compute="_get_unpaid_invoices")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation of string inside loop. generate a newline separated full string then write it on field

```
@api.one
@api.depends('customer_id')
def _get_unpaid_list(self):
    invoice_pool = self.env['account.invoice']
    unpaid_list = ''
    for rec in invoice_pool.search([('state', '=', 'open'), ('partner_id', '=', self.customer_id.id)]):
        amount_total = rec.amount_total or ''
        number = rec.number or ''
        name = ustr(amount_total) + "-" + ustr(number)
        if len(unpaid_list)>0:
            unpaid_list += '\n'
        unpaid_list += name
    self.unpaid_list = unpaid_list
```

Comment: thank you brother. It works too.